# .net standard 2.1 Class Library file nesting not supported

Tags: .net, .net-standard

Can somebody please explain why file nesting is not supported in .net standard libraries, it works perfectly fine in .net core projects

Comment: What do you mean not supported? Do you have any errors? And what version of .NET Standard project you create? Please describe and clarify in detail.

Comment: ok, your question's title says .NET Standard 2.1. Now please clarify the error or "not supported" problem.